# Stored Procedure are not executed due to master key restriction

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have complete backup of a database and restored it on my SQL Server successfully, but a problem shows up when I try to execute a stored procedure in that database.

Error message :

> Please create a master key in the database or open the
>   master key in the session before performing this operation.

I searched for this error and find out that I should create master key here on my server with decrypt information but how can I find this decrypt key?

How to solve this issue is the master is only provided by the one who created that once?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a [backup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174387%28SQL.90%29.aspx) of master key, you can [restore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186336%28SQL.90%29.aspx) it.

If you don't have a backup of master key and can not make it, you can try to it with password:

```
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = ‘your_password'
ALTER MASTER KEY ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY
```

I think it is impossible to get data if you don't have a backup of master have and don't konw the password

Comment: can you make a backup of master key ?

Comment: no please guide me.. As this backup is provided by someone else my need is to add some feature in existing website for that i need some stored procedures but due to master key restriction i am unable to do that.

Comment: 1. I have updated my answer 2. You can backup a master key using the command BACKUP MASTER KEY TO FILE = 'path_to_file' ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password'

Comment: password used in your query is provided by the creator of database.?

Comment: By creator of master key (CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'password').  One master key is used by all databases on this server.

Comment: When i execute the query you provided just now then it prompts this error "There is already a master key in the database. Please drop it before performing this statement."

Comment: You don't need to execute this query.  I post it to show you when the password was used (in the moment of kee creation).  You must get the password form the key creator.

Comment: when i executed your query with the password then my issue was resolved...
Thanks for the help